# Checkboxlist checked based on url $_GET

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to make my checkboxlist checked based on the current page url in Yii 1.1.15

in my view:

```
   $arr0 = array('1'=> 'store 1', '2'=> 'store 2', '3'=>'store 3' .......);
    echo $form->checkBoxList($model,'store', $arr0,
                                                array(
                                                      'name'=>'store',
                                                      'separator'=>'',
                                                      'template'=>'<span class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">{input}&nbsp;{label}</span>',
                                                      'uncheckValue'=>0
                                                )
                                    );
```

and my URL looks like this

```
url/?store=1,4,5,6
```

any idea how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set your array to your model before rendering `checkBoxList` like below:

```
$arr0 = array('1','2');
$model->store=$arr0;
```

Now, 1,2 will be marked as selected.